# file name matching

Tags: shell-script, csh

I have 2 folders with number of files with a pattern of

```
File-1 1234_-_abcdef_abcdefg.abc
File-2 1234_-_qwerty_abcdefg.abc
```

My code goes like

```
foreach d (`cat deck_list`) 
  foreach c (`cat cars_list`) 
    compute_blah_blah.py -f Deck_list/$d -s Cars_list/$c 
  end 
end
```

Now, I need to match 1234 part from both deck_list and cars_list
else just continue searching for the other ones in the same file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `awk`. The script is created with respect of the format in question

```
for file in $(ls dir1/)
do
a=$(echo $file| awk -F_ '{print $1}')
    ls dir2/ |awk -v name=$a -F_ '$1==name {print}' 
done
```

Comment: Hello Romeo, My script goes like this = foreach d (`cat deck_list`)
foreach c (`cat cars_list`)

compute_blah_blah.py -f Deck_list/$d -s Cars_list/$c
 

end
end
Now, I need to match 1234 part from both deck_list and cars_list

Comment: @user396007, please add this to the question. And properly format the code

Comment: @user396007, the code above is what you ask for. And I am not sure about the language you use for your script

Comment: I'm using python for computing stuffs in the shell script

Comment: Hi Romeo, Can't we use if else statement? something like if(1234 pattern in dock file matches with 1234 pattern in cars file only then compute else look for the other ones.

Comment: @user396007, this is what my script do. Feel free to change it according your requirements